# Access EC2 Instance using Basic Credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-java-sdk

I'm trying to use the Java SDK to programmatically stop an EC2 instance. I'm very new the AWS api, but what I'm trying to do should be very basic:

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);

AmazonEC2Client ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials); //ERROR caused by this line
```

I've seen several examples of this, for example [here](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1XG3FX6VMU6O5/A-safer-way-to-distribute-AWS-credentials-to-EC2). I know the better way to do this is by using IAM roles, but I'm just trying to get something to work first. The line that creates the AmazonEC2 throws this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper at com.amazonaws.util.json.Jackson.
```

I can't figure out why it's throwing a class definition not found error.

Comment: can you confirm the access key works or not? download `aws-cli ` (aws command tools) and run directly in shell scriping to confirm you can run the command successfully `aws ec2 describe-instance-status`

Comment: Ok, I did this and got a good response. I have a question though which maybe I should have included in the original post: if the credentials being wrong were the problem, wouldn't I have gotten a different error, not a class not found error? Or will the errors from the AWS api calls not be descriptive of the problem?

Comment: You can test from your end with failed access key.

Comment: What if the class not found error is thrown before it even checks the access key?

Comment: Can you try with this official doc (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-programming-techniques.html) ?

Comment: Yes, they give an example [here at the bottom](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/credentials.html), which is exactly what I'm doing except I'm making an EC2Client instead of an S3Client, so it should work. Also, I tried changing the access keys to the wrong ones and got the same error.

Comment: so you get same error with failed access key? then you didn't pass the first step. `access_key_id, secret_access_key` is not same as `ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY` , can you make sure, you have set the enviornment properly? such as : `echo $AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE`

Comment: I'm confused. If I'm getting a class not found error, wouldn't that break the line of code before it even checks if the keys are correct? Also, ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_KEY are hardcoded copied from the text file I used to configure the environmental variables for the command line test, so they should be the same.

EDIT: I'm at home now so I can't do anything else for today, but tomorrow I might try using the default credential chain instead of creating the credentials using hardcoded values, although theoretically it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Apparently the AWS library requires three more dependencies in [fasterxml.jackson.core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core). Because I was using Ivy to configure these, I had to add these manually